# Get rid of NaT and duplicates from a pandas dataFrame to obtain a series of datetime values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like shown picture [image]

Dataframe shape is (1944,900).
Each row of the dataframe has one value (it might be repeated multiple times based on the row index). I need to extract a list of 1944 numbers each representing valid value from each row (excluding NaT and duplicate values).

Any ideas on this?

Comment: To get helpful feedback quicker, please make sure to provide sample data as text, not image. Also, add some code you have tried, to give others an impression where you start.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for your advice. I will keep that in mind next time I post a question.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you could just get the values from the diagonal of this array right?  If so, then assuming your dataframe is called `df`

```
df.values[range(len(df)), range(len(df))]
```

will give you a numpy array of these values you want

Comment: @MrFuppes I did make a typo, thanks for picking it up, I have corrected it.

Comment: ok, `np.diag(df)` might be nice as well. Or `df.stack().unique()` if it's not a diagonal. Anyhow, OP should really provide a [mre], not some screenshot.

Comment: I didn't know about `np.diag`.  Good idea.

Comment: @Riley Thanks. The dataframe isn't a square so # of rows and # of columns aren't equal.

Comment: @HasibulJamil so if the "diagonal" method doesn't work for you, does `df.stack().unique()` work?